# Titanic Dataset cross validation Query

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I've been studying and playing around with this kaggle notebook. I'm also quite new to this as well.

https://www.kaggle.com/ldfreeman3/a-data-science-framework-to-achieve-99-accuracy#Step-5:-Model-Data

I'm up to step 5 - model data. I'm attempting to cross validate (if that's the correct term) all the algorithms listed in the code below, however it seems to output only  10 results instead of 21 :

```
cv_split = model_selection.ShuffleSplit(n_splits = 10, test_size = .3, train_size = .6, random_state = 0 )

data_c = ['Sex_Code','Pclass', 'Embarked_Code', 'Title_Code', 'FamilySize', 'AgeBin_Code', 'FareBin_Code']

Target = ['Survived]
```

```
   #Initialize and select algorithms by making a variable 
MLA = [#Ensemble Methods
    ensemble.AdaBoostClassifier(),
    ensemble.BaggingClassifier(),
    ensemble.ExtraTreesClassifier(),
    ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier(),
    ensemble.RandomForestClassifier(),

    #Gaussian Processes
    gaussian_process.GaussianProcessClassifier(),
    
    #GLM
    linear_model.LogisticRegressionCV(),
    linear_model.PassiveAggressiveClassifier(),
    linear_model.RidgeClassifierCV(),
    linear_model.SGDClassifier(),
    linear_model.Perceptron(max_iter=1000000),
    
    #Navies Bayes
    naive_bayes.BernoulliNB(),
    naive_bayes.GaussianNB(),
    
    #Nearest Neighbor
    neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(),
    
    #SVM
    svm.SVC(probability=True),
    svm.NuSVC(probability=True),
    svm.LinearSVC(dual= False),
    
    #Trees    
    tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(),
    tree.ExtraTreeClassifier(),
    
    #Discriminant Analysis
    discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(),
    discriminant_analysis.QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis(),]
```

```
    #Score model with cross validation 

for i in MLA: 
    model = i
    cv_results = model_selection.cross_validate(model, tts[data_c], np.ravel(tts[Target]), cv  = cv_split, return_train_score= True)
```

```
pd.DataFrame(cv_results)

OUTPUT: 
fit_time    score_time  test_score  train_score
0   0.000000    0.005007    0.805970    0.818352
1   0.003021    0.002016    0.787313    0.842697
2   0.000000    0.000000    0.828358    0.812734
3   0.002012    0.000000    0.776119    0.842697
4   0.005007    0.000000    0.839552    0.822097
5   0.000000    0.000000    0.809701    0.822097
6   0.002052    0.000000    0.794776    0.840824
7   0.003051    0.002046    0.817164    0.820225
8   0.004505    0.003554    0.835821    0.833333
9   0.004505    0.000000    0.847015    0.810861
```

I was wondering how I could score the remaining 11 Machine learning algorithms and please tell me what my error was as well.

Kind Regards!

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your results every time with this line of code:

```
for i in MLA: 
        model = i
        cv_results = model_selection.cross_validate(model, tts[data_c],..)
```

so the 10 rows you have are cross-validation results from each fold from the last model in your iteration, not from each model.

You can do collect them in a list and concatenate the final data frame:

```
cv_results = []
for model in MLA: 
 
    res = model_selection.cross_validate(model, tts[data_c], 
    np.ravel(tts[Target]), cv  = cv_split, return_train_score= True)
    cv_results.append(res)
```